# Labelling subfigures with cleveref

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have an image `image.png` that has some parts: a), b) and c). I put it in my text like

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
\caption{Some text here \label{fig:myfig}}
\end{figure}
```

I use `cleveref` to reference objects within the document. I want to be able to have only one figure, but to be able to generate references (with the hyperlinks) to each part of the figure, i.e. something like `\Cref{fig:myfig}[a]` so that cleveref transforms it to "Figure 1a)", or \Cref{fig:myfig}[a,c] transforms to "Figures 1a) and 1c)". Is this possible? How does one do it without creating separate images and creating subfigures? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at the subcaption package - it can do phantom subfigures which then be referenced by cleverref

Comment: Please make your code compilable as that's much more useful than a mere fragment. You can use e.g. `example-image` etc. for external graphics, as everyone (with a standard install) has those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the subcaption package provides a solution for this with `phantomsubcaption` ([see here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/subcaption.pdf)). An example is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{cat_and_elephant}
\phantomsubcaption\label{cat}
\phantomsubcaption\label{elephant}
\caption{Two animals: \subref{cat} a huge cat,
and \subref{elephant} an elephant}
\end{figure}
```